# How to use @overlays/vue correctly?

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am attempting to create a modal dialog (popup) in Vuetify which can ba called from code rathern than being contained in the html template. I have found [this library](https://github.com/hairyf/overlays) (vue specific instructions [here](https://unoverlays.vercel.app/en/vue/)) which appeasr to do excatly what I need. So I have created a component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import { useOverlay } from '@overlays/vue'
    
const props = defineProps<{
  title: String,
}>()
    
const { visible, resolve, reject } = useOverlay({
  // Duration of overlay duration to avoid premature destruction of the component
  duration: 1000,
})
</script>

<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="visible">
    <v-card>
    <v-card-text>{{ title }}</v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn color="primary" block @click="resolve(`${title}:confirmed`)">Close Dialog</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

and a way of using it:

```
import { renderOverlay } from '@overlays/vue'
import OverlayComponent from '../components/overlay.vue'

export async function myAlert() {
 
const value = await renderOverlay(OverlayComponent, {
  title: 'useOverlay'
})
}
```

When I call `myAlert`, the overlay appears , and will close if I click `CloseDialog`, but  both the title and the button text appear as plain text - all of the vuetify html components are ignored.

What am I missing here?